# Are a set of vectors in the kernel of A a subspace of A?

Tags: vector-spaces

My understanding of a subspace is confined to knowing they must satisfy three requirements: i) they are of vectors $R^n$ where n matches the space you're trying to subspace ii) the members of the subspace are closed under addition; iii) closed under multiplication.

Given this I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

For a transformation $T: R^3 \rightarrow R^4, V$ is the set of vectors $\bar{x}$ where $T(\bar{x})=0$. Is $V$ a subspace of $R^3$?

Since $V$ are the inputs they are of $R^3$ so that's fine, but I can't prove $T(x_1 + x_2 ) = T(x_1) + T(x_2) = 0$. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: Edited; it said "the"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel of a linear transformation is a subspace. Clearly, $T(0)=0$ and

if  $T(x)=0$ and $T(y)=0$  , then $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)=0+0=0$ and

if $T(x)=0$, then for any $c\in F$, $T(cx)=cT(x)=c\cdot 0=0$.

Remember to prove closure , first you have to assume you started in the set. So to show $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)=0$ , you must initially assume that $x,y\in V$, that is $T(x)=0$ and $T(y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof part. For understanding, how do I know x+y is still in the kernel? Is there a specific theorem that can affirm this?

Comment: @Five9 Since I showed  $T(x+y)=0$ , given $x,y$ are in the kernel ,$x+y$ is in the kernel . That’s is the definition of being in the kernel .

Answer (score 0):

- In general, the kernel of a linear transformation is always a subspace. However, not every subset of the kernel is a subspace.
- There is some ambiguity in your wording that may or may not be an issue. The problem *should* mean "$V$ is *the* set of vectors $\bar{x}$ where $T(\bar{x}) = 0$," rather than some possibly smaller subset of the kernel.
- Your last paragraph is fine (assuming $T$ is a *linear* transformation).

Comment: The original problem indeed had “the.” The OP has updated the question accordingly.